# Any free ASP.NET 3.5 App host?

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting

I want to host a test app in ASP.NET 3.5  but I can't find a decent free host anywhere!

I tried http://www.aspspider.com/ and after some days I still have a pending virtual directory creation.

Even if it has lots of banners with pub on it, it doesn't matter. I just want to try out something!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to try out something, there's always [the dynamic dns way](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/use-dynamic-dns-host-website-your-laptop).

And some dynamic dns providers: [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com/) and [no-ip](http://www.no-ip.com/)

Comment: thanks. 
But I didn't want to have my pc always on.
And to use the OpenId auth I need to have an external Ip...I think the dynamic dns wouldn't solve that.

But Thanks Anyway.

Answer (score 0):

what is the nature of your application? I might have some space for you on my server.

Comment: It's a photo gallery app, with:
 LiveMaps GoogleMaps
 OpenID Auth, Gmail Auth, Live Services (the 3.5 need)
Exif properties browsing (the 3.5 need)

I just have pieces of the app. but I wanted to try the google live open id component.
what do you thing about it?

Comment: do you need domain name too? or is it just for development? I think it's ok, Just drop your email on my website at www.arief.eu, I'll get back to you with all the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are also a lot of hosts which have x days free trials if it's just to test an app then just try one of those.

And there are offcourse also money back guarantees but that would be a bit more shady.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there's another thread that asks this same question, because I'm pretty sure that's where I got this link;

http://www.webhostforasp.net/freeaspwebhosting.aspx

It's temporarily closed right now while they make upgrades, but for anyone searching the forums in the future, it's worth checking out.

Comment: it's possible. but this question is more than one year old! but thanks anyway.